# Can't get values from SelectListItem

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm working in ASP.NET MVC
I want to bind a list of values on select list item (I only post relevant code)

Model:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int SubcategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Subcategory Subcategory { get; set; }
}
```

View Model:

```
 public class ProductViewModel
{
    public int SelectedSubcategory { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable <SelectListItem> Subcategory { get; set; }
}
```

Get Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var subcategoryList = new ProductViewModel
        {
            Subcategory = new SelectList(db.ProductsList, "SubcategoryId", "Name")
        };

        return View(subcategoryList);
    }
```

View:

```
 <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SubcategoryId, "SubcategoryId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedSubcategory, Model.Subcategory, "-Select an option-", new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SelectedSubcategory)
        </div>
    </div>
```

The problem it no binding values, I only get strong typed "-Select an option-", anyone have an idea what's wrong here?

-------------------------------------------------------------------Edit------------------------------------------------------------

Now I get parameters but I get error when I trying to create product:

Error message:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Products_dbo.Subcategories_SubcategoryId". The conflict occurred in database "proyectname", table "dbo.Subcategories", column 'SubcategoryId'.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Create post method:

```
 public async Task<string> CreateProduct(ProductViewModel model)
    {
        var product = new Product
        {
            Name = model.Name,
            Presentation = model.Presentation,
            Image = model.Image,
            Alt = model.Alt,
            SubcategoryId = model.SelectedSubcategory,
            IsDeleted = false
        };
        db.ProductsList.Add(product);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: You have to set the value of `SelectedSubcategory` in the view model before you pass the model to the view if you want a specific option to be selected.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Set it in `get controller`? I post what I have, but in create action = `post controller`

Comment: `var subcategoryList = new ProductViewModel { Subcategory = new SelectList(...), SelectedSubCategory = ## };` where `##` matches one of the options values that you want to select

Comment: I don't want to create values to select, I want to get from another table

Comment: What do you mean? You have said you the `"-Select an option-"` is selected when the page renders. If you want to have another option selected when you first generate the view, then you need to set the `SelectedSubCategory` property. Or do you mean that there is only one option in the dropdownlist?

Comment: I have a table that has ​​subcategories values , I want to take those values ​​and put them in my dropdown of the Products table , but the only value you get is  `"-Select an option-"`

Comment: If you want subcategories, why are you using `db.ProductsList`? You need to be using `db.SubCategories` (or what ever your subcategory table is named)

Comment: You're right, I change it but still get nothing into dropdown @StephenMuecke

Comment: Then your subcategories table does not contain any values.

Comment: Oops!, yes it's true I confuse a little bit because I have categories, I confuse it with subcategories, Thanks!

Comment: Why I get this error when I try to create one product? `The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Products_dbo.Subcategories_SubcategoryId". The conflict occurred in database "ProyectName", table "dbo.Subcategories", column 'SubcategoryId'.
The statement has been terminated.` @StephenMuecke

Comment: What is `productid` in `SubcategoryId = productid,`? It should be just `SubcategoryId = model.SelectedSubcategory,`

Comment: Yes, sorry I forget to change it, It just for testing, I change it, but I still get `FOREIGN KEY` error @StephenMuecke

Comment: I assume this is related to the nonsense in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37241791/the-insert-statement-conflicted-with-the-foreign-key-constraint-dropdownlist)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

### Controller:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    Viewbag.SubcategoryId= new SelectList(db.ProductsList, "SubcategoryId", "Name")

    return View();
}
```

### View:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SubcategoryId, "SubcategoryId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("SubcategoryId", null, "-Select an option-", new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SubcategoryId)
    </div>
</div>
```