# The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint dropdownlist

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm working in ASP.NET MVC Web Application, so I want to insert values from another table (I get it with dropdownlist), but when I try to post, I get this:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_dbo.Products_dbo.Subcategories_SubcategoryId". The conflict
>   occurred in database "ProyectName", table "dbo.Subcategories", column
>   'SubcategoryId'. The statement has been terminated.

Products model:

```
 public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; } 
    public int SubcategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Subcategory Subcategory { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Presentation { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public string Alt { get; set; } 
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
```

Product ViewModel

```
 public class ProductViewModel
{

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Presentation { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public string Alt { get; set; }
    public int SelectedSubcategory { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable <SelectListItem> Subcategory { get; set; }

}
```

Subcategory Model:

```
 public class Subcategory
{
    public int SubcategoryId { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public string Alt { get; set; }
    public string Pdf { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public bool IsInstalled { get; set; }
}
```

Get Controller

```
   public ActionResult Create()

    {
        var subcategoryList = new ProductViewModel
        { 
            Subcategory = new SelectList(db.SubcategoriesList, "SubcategoryId", "Name") 
        }; 

        return View(subcategoryList);
    }
```

Post Controller(Service method):

```
  public class ProductService : IProductService
{
    private EfDatabase db = new EfDatabase();

    public async Task<string> CreateProduct(ProductViewModel model)
    {
        var product = new Product
        {
            Name = model.Name,
            Presentation = model.Presentation,
            Image = model.Image,
            Alt = model.Alt,
            SubcategoryId = model.SelectedSubcategory,
            IsDeleted = false
        };
        db.ProductsList.Add(product);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return "Product " + model.Name + "has been created";
```

View:

```
  @model Proyect.Models.ViewModels.ProductViewModel

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

 <h2>Create</h2>

 @using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Product</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SubcategoryId, "SubcategoryId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedSubcategory, Model.Subcategory, "-Selecciona una opcion-", new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SelectedSubcategory)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Presentation, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Presentation, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Presentation, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Image, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Image, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Image, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Alt, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Alt, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Alt, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

So I don't found any error on my code, what's wrong with that? can any one help me to solve this problem?

My question is unique because model.SelectedSubcategory don't get Id value from another table, It always get 0 so in the other questions no make any comparision with that

Thankyou in advance!

MY CREATE VIEW NOW

```
@model myPROYECT.Models.ViewModels.ProductViewModel

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

 @using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()


<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Product</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedSubcategory, Model.Subcategory, "-Selecciona una opcion-", new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SelectedSubcategory)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Presentation, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Presentation, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Presentation, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Image, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Image, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Image, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Alt, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Alt, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Alt, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    }

<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your Create action method and see what is the value of `model.SelectedSubCategory` and see whether that is a valid SubCategory id

Comment: `model.SelectedSubCategory` get value `0` @Shyju

Comment: Did use selects an item from the dropdown before submitting ?

Comment: Yes, I have one value addition than `"-Selecciona una opcion-"`, I select it and I get error @Shyju

Comment: but if I select null value  `"-Selecciona una opcion-"`, I also  get `0` into `model.SelectedSubCategory` @Shyju

Comment: Is there a any data with SubcategoryID=0 in Subcategory table?

Comment: No, SubcategoryId=12,  @shamimreza

Comment: Why I always get 0 instead if 12? @Shyju

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. It should give you the id of the selected sub category from the dropdown.

Comment: Yap, I get values fine and I have it into my dropdown, but the problem is in post action, I don't know why it returns Constraint FK :/

Comment: If you select "-Selecciona una opcion-"` it posts back `null` and you get a `ModelState` error. Because you property is `int` which can never be `null` it is set the the default (`0`) value. If you do not want to have a subcategory associated with `Product`, then you need to make property `nullable`

Comment: Instead of null value, I have another value that get dron another subcategory table, but if I select it, it get value 0 top @StephenMuecke

Comment: From your comments in Saqib Rokadia's answer, it you select the 2 option (`<option value="12">Subcategory1</option>`) then the value of `model.SelectedSubcategory` will be `12` (not `0`). And why does your view model have both `public int SubcategoryId { get; set; }` and `public int SelectedSubcategory { get; set; }`?

Comment: Yes un returns 0 instead 12, and you mean I only need selectedsubcategory and not subcategoryid?@StephenMuecke

Comment: No you do not need `subcategoryid`. And if the value of `model.SelectedSubcategory` is `0` even if you select the 2nd option, then it suggests you have a hidden input for property `SelectedSubcategory` in the view before your dropdownlist (or the code you have shown is not the real code)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I remove `subcategoryid` and I send via hidden input like `@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.SelectedSubcategory)`, but still no works, I update changes on question, and yes is my real code

Comment: No. Did you not understand my last comment. You **cannot** have a hidden input for `SelectedSubcategory`. Remove `@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.SelectedSubcategory)` and it will all work fine.

Comment: And DO NOT keep changing your original question! If you have tried other code then append it to the question.

Comment: I delete it and still get FK issue :/, the view I posted is just copy paste of my VS @StephenMuecke

Comment: If you select the 2nd option which has a value of `12` then the value of `model.SelectedSubcategory` WILL BE `12` in the POST method. If its not, then the code you have shown is not the real code.

Comment: It's 0 , and its my real code, I just copy paste it, that's very strange!

Comment: You did not copy/paste it because you view would throw an exception - the view model no longer contain a property `SubcategoryId` so `@Html.LabelFor(model => model.SubcategoryId, ...)` will result in an error.

Comment: @StephenMuecke that's because I edit my view after create helper

Comment: Added what to you view? The code you have shown will throw an exception because `ProductViewModel` does not contain a property named `SubcategoryId`

Comment: Ughh that's because another coment I change it, but I upload  now what I have @StephenMuecke

Comment: Oh no shit, thanks for it, that gives me an idea why it fails, and I see in post controller, I have Bind Values, I just need to add selectedValue to bind, incredible but true!, post method I upload is an extension of post method, so in post method I binding values and thats my error, it solved now. Thanks for all @StephenMuecke

Comment: There is no `[Bind]` attribute in the code you have shown! When I said show the real code I meant **show the real code**!

Comment: Its real code but post method I do is a extension method, so post controller only redirect action to it, and I no consider relevant update original controller until I see Bind attribute  :@

Comment: Why in the world would you have a `BindAttribute` if your using a view model. Suggest you delete your question - its of no use to anyone

Comment: Okay I'll delete it, but can you explain me why I dont need Bind if I have view model?

Comment: Because its a view model and a view model contains only the properties you need for editing (and in the POST method you map the view model properties to an instance of the data model. You already protected against over-posting attacks so a `[Bind]` attribute is pointless.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing that requires a Subcategory to be selected. You're likely to get this error when a selection hasn't been made for subcategory. You should make subcategory required or make null a value that's possible to get back.

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; } 
    public int? SubcategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Subcategory Subcategory { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Presentation { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public string Alt { get; set; } 
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}


using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class ProductViewModel
{
    public int? SubcategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Presentation { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public string Alt { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int? SelectedSubcategory { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable  Subcategory { get; set; }
}
```

Post Controller(Service method):

```
public class ProductService : IProductService
{
    private EfDatabase db = new EfDatabase();

    public async Task<string> CreateProduct(ProductViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View("Create");

        var product = new Product
        {
            Name = model.Name,
            Presentation = model.Presentation,
            Image = model.Image,
            Alt = model.Alt,
            SubcategoryId = model.SelectedSubcategory,
            IsDeleted = false
        };
        db.ProductsList.Add(product);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return "Product " + model.Name + "has been created";
    }
}
```

Comment: That's no make sense, the problem debugging it, is that model.SelectedSubcategory is always 0, and the unique subcategory I have Id is 0

Comment: So basically the default option in the form is "-Selecciona una opcion-" which should have an empty value. MVC will try to coerce that value to an int which means you'll get the default value of an int which is 0. So it will try to insert with 0 which probably does not exist in the subcategory table which is the error you're getting. However if you're getting 0 for every option then I need more information.

How does the html look like for the dropdown? Also just to be sure the dropdown has to be wrapped in a `<% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>` and `<% } %>`

Comment: Yes it is into using, I upload complete view into my question

Comment: any idea why I have this problem?

Comment: So when I said HTML. I was referring to what ended up in the browser. So right-click on the dropdown and inspect element.

Comment: Alright, I get this `<select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field SelectedSubcategory must be a number." data-val-required="The SelectedSubcategory field is required." id="SelectedSubcategory" name="SelectedSubcategory"><option value="">-Selecciona una opcion-</option>
<option value="12">Subcategory1</option>
</select>`

Comment: The html looks good. So for the Post method is it just `[HttpPost] public void Create(ProductViewModel model)` otherwise it needs to be something like `Http.BeginForm("CreateProduct")`. Everything else looks good otherwise.